# Connect to Windows SQL Server 2008 R2 from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, freetds, tiny-tds

My Rails 4.2.1 app has to connect to a Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 database. I am using the `tiny_tds` gem version 1.0.4. FreeTDS v1.00.15 is installed on the production server running Ubuntu 14.04.

I run queries inside an each loop and I can't get the loop to complete, the process crashes before completion.
I tried playing with tiny_tds options without success.

Here's the code I am using to get the tiny_tds client (check `tds_version` and `timeout` options):

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new(username: db_conf['username'], password: db_conf['password'], host: db_conf['host'], port: db_conf['port'], database: db_conf['database'], tds_version: '7.3', timeout: 15000, appname: 'ERP')
```

Here's the FreeTDS log after such an error happens.

> packet.c:741:Sending packet 0000 12 01 00 ce 00 00 00 00-16 03 01 00
>   86 10 00 00 |........ ........| 0010 82 00 80 6e d9 e2 dc 97-9d 77 59
>   9a 5b da e3 e2 |...n.... .wY.[...| 0020 8b aa 66 ed ec 5e e2 02-e5 6c
>   fd db e1 ef 47 1a |..f..^.. .l....G.| 0030 9d 63 03 ed 6d 3e 28 3b-b9
>   64 fd 92 71 34 ff ba |.c..m>(; .d..q4..| 0040 7d 3c 8d ee 7b 34 75
>   e9-d5 b7 c6 83 a9 7d e6 7f |}<..{4u. .....}..| 0050 71 7e 25 11 82 b8
>   76 b1-c6 ba 86 b4 c3 0a 47 f0 |q~%...v. ......G.| 0060 51 96 c7 e2 5f
>   ca 07 b2-95 53 b9 9e bb 2c e7 cb |Q..._... .S...,..| 0070 be 0a b5 eb
>   b0 f3 41 1d-cd 86 fc a6 53 08 5e 56 |......A. ....S.^V| 0080 29 85 79
>   14 dc 2b 74 7b-b2 43 2c e8 0e 87 60 e4 |).y..+t{ .C,...`.| 0090 10 ef
>   f8 14 03 01 00 01-01 16 03 01 00 30 c7 f0 |........ .....0..| 00a0 35
>   f5 2c 6e 79 8d 85 b9-bd 60 b7 09 8c 7e 29 18 |5.,ny... .`...~).| 00b0
>   4a 56 ea c3 4e 13 bf e3-c5 8d f6 68 31 31 54 ee |JV..N... ...h11T.|
>   00c0 bf 2f 75 8d e9 9e c0 a9-d0 d2 9e 5b c9 92       |./u..... ...[..|
>
> tls.c:105:in tds_pull_func_login query.c:3796:tds_disconnect()
>   util.c:165:Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
>   util.c:322:tdserror(0x80b75e0, 0xa04ca80, 20017, 0)
>   dblib.c:7947:dbperror(0xae62780, 20017, 0) dblib.c:8015:dbperror:
>   Calling dblib_err_handler with msgno = 20017; msg->msgtext =
>   "**Unexpected EOF from the server** (192.168.32.105:1433)"
>   dblib.c:5777:dbgetuserdata(0xae62780) dblib.c:8037:dbperror:
>   dblib_err_handler for msgno = 20017; msg->msgtext = "Unexpected EOF
>   from the server (192.168.32.105:1433)" -- returns 2 (INT_CANCEL)
>   util.c:352:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
>   util.c:375:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2) util.c:375:tdserror:
>   returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2) tls.c:942:handshake failed
>   login.c:530:login packet rejected util.c:322:tdserror(0x80b75e0,
>   0xa04ca80, 20002, 0) dblib.c:7947:dbperror(0xae62780, 20002, 0)
>   dblib.c:8015:dbperror: Calling dblib_err_handler with msgno = 20002;
>   msg->msgtext = "Adaptive Server connection failed"

And here's the output of `tsql -C`:

```
~$ tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v1.00.15
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: auto
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: no
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
                            OpenSSL: yes
                             GnuTLS: no
                               MARS: no
```

Any idea what I should do to fix those `Unexpected EOF from the server` errors?

Comment: What version of FreeTDS is installed? You should be able to run `tsql -C` to see. If you're on 0.91, you'll need to use `tds_version: '7.2'`; 7.3 required 0.95 or higher.

Comment: @FlipperPA It seems I am using FreeTDS 0.91 (installed from Ubuntu packet manager). Using `tds_version: '7.2'`, I get the same `Unexpected EOF from server` error though.

Comment: Using `tds_version: '7.2'` will save you headaches down the road (especially if you deal with Unicode) if you're on 0.91. But back to the matter at hand: can you connect with `tsql`? For example, `TDSVER=7.2 tsql -H 192.168.32.105 -p 1433 -U your_username`? If that doesn't work, can you `telnet 192.168.32.105 1433` and connect? Also, if you have non-alpha characters in your password, you may want to try a short(ish) alphanumeric password, less than 20 characters. Older versions of FreeTDS had a 25-char max size on username and password (but I *think* they were increased by 0.91).

Comment: @FlipperPA The connection is OK, I am able to send queries and get results. The problem is that FreeTDS crashes on some big SELECT queries with the `Unexpected EOF from the server ` error. I am looking for a solution on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the SQL Profiler, I found out the Rails application was opening way too many connections on the MSSQL server. Upon reaching its max number of open connection, the MSSQL server refused opening any new connection, resulting in the `Unexpected EOF from the server` error.

To solve the issue, I had to reuse my open connection when sending queries instead of opening a new connection for each query. I guess this is the correct way to use the `tiny_tds` connector anyway.

Translated to code:

```
def self.get_pmi_client
  if @@pmi_client.nil? or !@@pmi_client.active?
    db_conf = Rails.configuration.database_configuration["pmi_#{Rails.env}"]
    @@pmi_client = TinyTds::Client.new(username: db_conf['username'], password: db_conf['password'], host: db_conf['host'], port: db_conf['port'], database: db_conf['database'])
    raise MSSQLConnectionError, t('erp.errors.pmi_connection_error') unless @@pmi_client.active?
  end
  return @@pmi_client
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FreeTDS configuration (often in `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` as in your configuration), change the value of `text size`:

```
text size = 4294967295
```

That's the maximum value, IIRC. I believe with FreeTDS 0.91 that your default is probably 64512.